# I dont understand apache access log file

Tags: java, apache, security, logfile

there are a apache log file example. But I didn't understand which one is status code, and other strings in the response:

> 64.242.88.10 - - [07/Mar/2004:16:05:49 -0800] "GET /twiki/bin/edit/Main/Double_bounce_sender?topicparent=Main.ConfigurationVariables
>   HTTP/1.1" 401 12846

Can you help me understand?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Piece by piece these are the meanings:

**64.242.88.10** => Client IP adress

**--** => The second hyphen is the userID (hyphen means the document that you wnt to get is not protected with password)

**[07/Mar/2004:16:05:49 -0800]** => Timestamp of the request

**"GET /twiki/bin/edit/Main/Double_bounce_sender?topicparent=Main.ConfigurationVariables**  => This is the resource that you wanted to retrieve

**HTTP/1.1"** => Protocol used

**401** => Status code (this means unathorized)

**12846** => Size of the object to be returned

Comment: Thank you for your support.